# Oslo Sandefjord train to Oslo Gardemoen

Tags: airports, oslo

What is the best connection between these two Oslo airports? Distance and time needed?

Comment: Do you mean from TRF (Sandefjord lufthavn) to OSL (Oslo lufthavn)? There is no "Oslo Sandefjord" airport and Gardermoen was dropped from the name 5 years ago. If so, you have to tell when you are going. Rail traffic is interrupted due to construction works at least until August 5th and time tables vary depending on time and weekday.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo But there is a Oslo Sandefjord train ...

Comment: @CGCampbell Oslo and Sandefjord are two cities, about 120km apart and yes, they have a rail connection, which is currently interrupted due to construction works. The body of the question talks about two airports though.